# Using Webpack and stylus to create static css

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, webpack, stylus

new to Webpack. I was thinking about migrating JS part of my application to it. However, I don't like the way it handles CSS. Would like to keep it easy and link them on my own. Unfurtunately documentation wasn't very helpful, same with the search results.

So, what do I need exactly?

1. Stylus compilation from lots of .styl files to static .css.
2. There will be three static stylesheet files (entry points?), but completely different from entry points of JS part of an application.
3. Also some "watch" feature, which would compile css when one of source .styl files has been changed.

Is there somebody who could point me in right direction, maybe write a config? Is this even possible with Webpack or should I stay with Grunt?

Thanks for any useful answer.

Comment: I have [a tip on that](https://github.com/taxigy/til/blob/master/webpack/css-modules-webpack.md), just replace SCSS with Stylus everywhere. Watch comes with Webpack (see [docs](https://webpack.github.io/docs/tutorials/getting-started/)). And please do your own research first.

Comment: Sorry Rishat, but this actually doesn't help, I need static css generated, not a css modules.

Answer (score -2):

To learn more about the details of Webpack you can refer to this online book [SurviveJS - Webpack](http://survivejs.com/webpack/introduction/), which will walk you through most of concepts related to Webpack.
To accomplish what you need you can start by creating `webpack.config.js` in the root of your project and it can be like this:

```
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = { 
    entry: './entry.js', // you application entry point
    output: {
        filename: 'bundle.js', // resulting bundle file
        path: './public' // the output folder path
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.styl$/,
                loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract("style", "!css!stylus") // plugin used to extract css file from your compiled `styl` files
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new ExtractTextPlugin('style.css') // output css bundle
    ]
};
```

Then require your stylus files in you `entry.js` file `require('./style.styl');`

Don't forget to install required loaders and plugins

```
npm install --save-dev css-loader sass-loader style-loader extract-text-webpack-plugin
```